# Configuration of DCEVM on an existing project

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, hotswap, dcevm

How I can configure DCEVM in existing project in Intellij step by step? I get plugin DCEVM Integration and HotSwapAgent in Intelij alsow I have a jar file DCEVM-8u181-installer form my java version.

**Edit:**

**Manula to install**
[image]